# Contents of /public in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have mistakenly deleted the files from the /public in Laravel.  Can anyone direct me on how to get a copy of these files so I can put them back?

Thanks for any thoughts....

Answer (score 3):

You could [create a new Laravel project](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation) in a different directory and copy the public folder over to your existing project, or you could get the files from the [official repository on GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/public).